# How to display mouse cursor position end of word by default in input text box angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do you display mouse cursor position at the end of text in an input text box by default using angularJS?

I used `auto focus`, It looks fine for all browsers other than `IE browser`.

Comment: Please describe your issue clearly and add some code that you have tried so far.

Comment: I am using angularjs model window and below is the input text box.     <input type="text"
           class="form-control"
           ng-model="vm.title"
           ng-keydown="$event.which === 13 && vm.submit($event)"
           placeholder="Title"
           autofocus>

Answer (score 0):

I hope the below method will solve your problem.

```
<input id="search" type="text" value="mycurrtext" size="30" 
       onfocus="this.value = this.value;" name="search"/>
```

This works in both IE7 and FF3

Comment: Thank for your response.. I tried but this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I researched more on this my question and found the answer myself. This answer might be helpful if anyone looking for the same kind of answer.

1. Created the Custom Directive and added that into HTML button element.

   function mouseDisplayDIsplayEndCharInTextBoxIEIssus($timeout) {
           return {
               restrict: 'AE',
               link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                   var titleLength;
                   function model(scope){
                       titleLength = scope.vm.title.length;
                   }
                   scope.$watch(model, function() {
                           $timeout(function() {
                               element[0].focus();
                               element[0].setSelectionRange(titleLength, titleLength);
                           });

   ```
               });
           }
       };
   }
   ```